# FindPython vs find_package(Python ....)

Tags: python, cmake, find-package

In CMake 3.12 the [`FindPython`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html) module was introduced to help find the Python interpreter and other components.

However, I continue to see many examples using `find_package(Python ...)`.

Which should I use if I can guarantee I'm using CMake 3.12? What is the relationship between the two?

Comment: That _is_ using the `FindPython` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. The `find_package(Python ...)` call looks for a module named `FindPython.cmake` first in `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, then in the standard CMake installation folder (where it will be found for sure).

Are you expecting to see `include(FindPython)`? If so, that's bad practice. One should only load `FindXYZ.cmake` modules via `find_package(XYZ)`. This applies all the way back to CMake 2.x.

> Which should I use if I can guarantee I'm using CMake 3.12?

You should use `find_package(Python ...)`, exactly as the documentation suggests. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython.html

Comment: Thanks Alex, this resolved my confusion.

Comment: @BeeOnRope To make sure your project gonna be built w/ the required CMake you can^W have to use `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)` as the very first statement of your `CMakeLists.txt`.